# Efficiently sync/create a dimensions and facts tables from a very large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pipeline

I have very large table that contains repeated dimensions as strings and it has more than 40 million rows. This table is populated with millions of records every day.

The facts and dimensions table would reflect the information inside the very large table. The facts and dimensions are updated with the new information inserted in the big table and the operation should be fast (considering millions of new rows are inserted in the big table every day)

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's is the pipeline I assume is the most efficient and fast

[image]

Is there any way to do this pipeline efficently in SQL Server? Is there another method that would be faster?

Comment: I think usually one does the other way around, separate table populate the "big" table

Comment: Yes, it is an option to separate the data on the programming language (Python) side and then insert it to the separate facts and dimension tables. However, the volumetry is very big in this case and I was wondering if it already exists a common solution in SQL Server for this problem that is faster

Comment: I tried to do this pipeline of inserting first the data and it's much slower than splitting into facts and dimension tables because of the overhead of having to transport to the database lots of repeated text columns (dimensions). I was using `bcp` (the fastest available method). I will probably first separate the facts and the dimensions in Python and then import the results with `bcp`

Answer (score 1):

While it is straightforward to update a FCT table from given large table (you have to select fact columns from big table and insert them into FCT table), updating a DIM table from a given big table poses one major problem - slowly changing dimensions.

In the big table - It is theoretically possible to have different car names (or any car detail) for the same car ID. In such a case your dim table would also have to track history of changes to a particular car ID. This is so that you can correctly join the FCT and DIM tables to get back your original table.

To overcome this you will have to add the `date_transaction` field from your big table to the DIM table, effectively creating a composite key (id, date_transaction) on the DIM table.

Your flow would look like

[image: Flow diagram]

Note - Filtering out new DIM rows that have changed can be an expensive process. However, not doing so will mean your DIM table has as many rows as your FCT table (which kind of beats the purpose of decomposing).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much @sud for this elaborated answer with the nice diagram. I understand more or less the process/pipeline needed to convert one big table to dimensions table. I was asking if there exists any tool/SQL statement that can solve this problem efficently. 

I tried to insert the big table and then perform SQL operations to create/update the dimensions table, however, this process was much slower than elaborating the dimensions table in Python and later uploading all the results to the database.

Comment: Sorry for being AWOL. No direct query/tool comes to mind for SQL specifically. Not sure if delta lake is relevant for your architecture but worth checking out - https://delta.io/